# JFET as an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, analog, jfet

I'm working on this circuit below:

[image]

What is the functionality of R2 here? Stabilizing the input voltage? (If it was, it would've been connected in series, right?)

Comment: Without R2 the gate would be "floating" - but the transistor needs a fixed bias voltage between G and S.

Comment: A note for later:  Art of Electronics 2nd ed. §3.0.8 recommends **against** FET amplifiers. They recommend the FET **only** as a buffering input stage, then followed by more traditional BJT amplification stages. You also see this topology on FET input op amps like [AD824](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD824.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *What is the functionality of R2 here*

It's used to bias the gate to 0 volts. Because an N channel JFET works with a range of negative voltages on the gate with respect to the source, biasing this way ensures that the JFET conducts a few mA of current causing the source to rise to a positive value. At this point equilibrium is reached due to negative feedback.

Comment: @andre314 can you explain this: *gate current is no small*?

Comment: I can explain through a example (maybe 2N4391), because it can't be explained without some insight about the orders of magnitude of the values.

Comment: @andre314 no, you misunderstand me. You said: gate current is \$\boxed{\text{no}}\$ small. In other words, it doesn't read correctly so, do you mean \$\boxed{\text{so}}\$ or do you mean \$\boxed{\text{not}}\$? Engineers need to be precise.

Comment: I'm just discovering a awfull typo : I mean "so small" (not "no small"). Sorry

Comment: I think the best is to remove my comment and add a new one. I Will do that in 10 minutes.

Comment: @andre314 OK, next... why might old-timers find BJT more difficult to understand compared to JFETs? Why specifically do you say "old timers"?

Comment: @Andy my answer hints at that...

Comment: (my comment corrected :) For JFET the gate current is so small that the voltage drop through R2 can be considered to be 0 Volts (even If R2 is large, say 1 Megohm). FET are simplier to bias than BJT. In fact they are exactly like triodes, and that's why some people have found BJT more difficult to understand than triodes (in the 1960s)

Comment: @Andyaka: speaking only from my own experience (and yes, the first books I studied were all about tubes, not these new-fangled transistor thingies), when I finally did study transistors, I found FETs much easier to grasp than BJTs.

Answer (score 3):

Establishing the DC value of the grid*cough*gate at 0V.

Note the J in JFET : positive signal peaks can forward-bias the junction, charging C1. In normal operation the gate current is minuscule, but this no longer applies when the junction becomes forward biassed.

When the input signal returns to 0, the bias voltage is now negative thanks to the charge on C1, reducing the drain current or even cutting off the FET.

R2 allows this charge to dissipate returning the bias to 0V and the correct drain current to flow.

(In older texts, from the days of glassFETs, R2 was called a "grid leak" resistor!)

Comment: Perhaps convert it to a footnote and refer to it on the first sentence (by "\[1\]")?

Answer (score 2):

**Philosophy.** In my answer I will try to expose the philosophy of this kind of biasing called "sorce (emitter, cathode) degeneration". Saying "philosophy", I mean not only to describe *what* is made but to explain *why* it is made this way...

**Problem.** We have to ensure some initial input voltage across the gate-source junction so that the transistor starts working even before the input voltage is applied. This "bias voltage" should be stable so that the drain current is stable... and the DC output (drain) voltage is stable as well.

**Self-biasing.** The clever trick of such *self-biasing* is that the transistor itself creates the necessary bias voltage by passing its current through the resistor Rs in the source; then it keeps up this voltage drop almost constant by the mechanism of the negative feedback.

*Implementation.* The bias voltage drop across Rs should be applied to the transistor input - the gate-source junction. How do we do it?

Fortunately, the N channel JFET requires a negative gate-source bias voltage. The source is already connected to the positive (upper) end of Rs; all that remains is to connect the gate to the negative (lower) end of Rs. How do we connect it?

The simplest way is to connect the gate directly (by a "piece of wire") to the lower end of Rs. And this is actually done in stages that do not require additional input voltage, such as JFET 2-terminal current sources (aka *constant-current diodes*).

When there is an input voltage (this case), we have to somehow add that voltage to the bias voltage. The simplest way is by connecting it in series. If the input source is "galvanic" (with a DC internal resistance), we can insert it directly between the gate and ground. In our case it is not possible because of the input coupling capacitor C1. The solution is to make the connection through a resistor (R2) with high resistance. Then the gate is galvanically connected through R2 to ground and the AC input voltage is applied through C1 to R2. As a result, a total voltage VIN + VRs is applied across the gate-source junction as needed.

**Mixed biasing.** But what do we do when the transistor is NMOS or NPN BJT... so it requires a positive bias voltage... and we do not want to give up the clever "source degeneration"?

Then we recall the simple classic biasing through an input voltage divider that would work here. But why not combine the two techniques?

*Implementation.* For this purpose, we add another *gate bias voltage* Vg in series to the *source bias voltage* Vs... and adjust Vg so that Vg > Vs. The total bias voltage between the gate and source will be positive as needed (Vbias = Vg - Vs > 0). So, in this case, the bias voltage is a difference between two partial bias voltages (they are grounded but the difference is "floating").

*Operation.* This technique is visualized in a geometrical way for the case of a BJT in the picture below. The voltages and voltage drops are represented by voltage bars (in red and warm colors) with proportional height and relevant position. The currents are represented by current loops (in green) with proportional thickness and relevant trajectory (only the base current is not shown... maybe it us forgotten).

[image: AC emitter follower]

As you can see, VBE = VB - VE is always positive; you can also see how the input voltage VIN (EIN) is "lifted" by VC1 (see also another [relevant answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/540311/61398)). To be more precise, we have to say that three voltages (VIN, VC1 and Ve) form the total base-emitter voltage.

I believe you will appreciate the power of this geometric approach of visualization...

Comment: interesting visualization. Though wouldn't it be thinking in terms of currents?

Comment: @Pete W, I made this picture in 2000. But the idea for this way of visualization came to me in the early 90's. Here are some ideas sketched in my [archive](https://photos.app.goo.gl/cMgnjorToXdRYKCLA) on sheets of paper yellowed by time...

Comment: almost 30 years later, there are now tools that make a similar visualization (without the superposition, however), such as here https://tinyurl.com/y82uxhzp (something I was recently figuring out). It would be important to freeze it in time to get any analytical insight from it ...

Comment: @Pete W, If I have to be honest, this visualization looks pretty bad and it is quite primitive... but there is room for improvement. Only to add that all these things are just tools that can't undo the need to think with our brains. As you can see from my answers, I always reveal what the idea behind the circuit is and how it is implemented in the case. Everything else just helps. We should not oppose the means to the goal and the form to the content...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking they must have all the pieces in there, needed to decompose into multiple loops. I can see that the act of drawing it is a way to make someone think about it, or to learn how to explain it better.

Comment: @Pete W, Once you are interested in visualization techniques, here is the further development of the voltage bars in [voltage diagrams](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film). I invented it also [in the early 90s](https://photos.app.goo.gl/aeQJAx4sqDEYDdtN8). And here is an attractive real experiment based on Apple II and the AD periphery MICROLAB - [living voltage diagram](https://photos.app.goo.gl/GMJoHDWTEMfx37Sp7)... which can give another idea to the designers of simulation programs... to make them more attractive to buyers...

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. To clarify, I am working on the circuit, not the simulation program- I just think it is interesting, and helpful to me to learn all the things I never learned right the first time!

Comment: @Pete W, That is great... I am doing the same thing as I understand more and more circuit ideas. It would be very nice to discuss principles, concepts, smart circuit ideas... Last month I did something I should have done a long time ago - I started a blog [Circuit Stories](https://circuitstories.blogspot.com/) where I began collecting materials and links to everything I have created on the web, including what I am doing right now. I think it would be interesting for you...